# WQL returns different results on C# and PowerShell

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I am running this WQL "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Started=true" on both C# and PowerShell but the results returned are different. Some of the services which are in running mode are not found in the list when query via C#.

C# code:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher s1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Started=true");
        ManagementObjectCollection qCollection = s1.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in qCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service: '{0}'", mo["Name"]);
        }
```

PowerShell code:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Started=true"
$results = Get-WmiObject -Query $query
$results|Export-Csv -path .\temp\service.csv -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0):

Added Impersonation in the C# code and issue resolved now. 
[To connect to WMI remotely with C# (System.Management)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx)